# How to subscribe to an ongoing http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I need to request some data from the server only once, then use it as long as the app is loaded

```
getData(callback: Function) {
 if (this.data) {
  callback(this.data);
 } else {
  this.query.http.get('url', res => {
   this.data = res;
   callback(this.data);
  });
 }
}
```

the problem is that when the app starts a lot of components request the data at once, resulting in 30-40 http request, so I came up with this solution:

```
getData(callback: Function) {
 if (this.data) {
  callback(this.data);
 } else if(!this.gettingData) {
  this.gettingData = true;
  this.query.http.get('url', res => {
   this.data = res;
   callback(this.data);
  });
 } else {
  setTimeout(() => {
   getData(callback);
  }, 500)
 }
}
```

so it requests the data again after 500ms if the http request is in progress, if the request returns an error I reset the gettingdata to false, it works, but it feels dirty and wrong, how can I subscribe to the ongoing http request called by another function invoker?

Comment: *the problem is that when the app starts a lot of components request the data at once, resulting in 30-40 http requests* - wouldn't this be a good time to rethink your design ? maybe introduce a service, provided at root, and injected to requiring components ?

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
getData () {
    this.query.http.get('url'). subscribe(
    res=> this.data = res,
    err=> console.log(err));
}
```

then just use this.data throughout your component, you could emit the data if it's from a child component like so

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

private data;

getData () {
    this.query.http.get('url'). subscribe(
    res=> {
          this.data = res;
          this.valueChange.emit(this.data);
    },
    err=> console.log(err));
}
```

i hope this helps. or somewhat answers your question

Comment: thank you, the get data is used in a service, doing so would mean that I have to subscribe to that event emitter in every single component, unsubscribe on destroy, I considered that option but it'd add a lot of clutter into the code

Answer (score 0):

introduce a service which manages your http requests. A service is basically a singleton which can be used via dependency injection.
Create it with

```
ng -generate service myservice
```

and inject it by declaring a field of type `myservice` as a constructor argument of your component.